# No funciona un botón en el celular dentro de un div.col-

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<div class"row"><div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.location = 'lista.php?grado=6-1'">6-1</button></div></div>
```

En computador el botón se ejecuta normalmente, pero hago la prueba en el celular y el botón no realiza ninguna operación. Desafortunadamente los celulares no tienen la consola para ver los errores :P
La versión de Bootstrap es 3.3.5
¿Alguna idea de lo que está sucediendo?
 De antemano gracias.

Comment: Que navegador usas en el celular?

Comment: Google Chrome xD

Comment: Y si agregas ```;``` al ```onclick="document.location = 'lista.php?grado=6-1'"```? Asi ```onclick="document.location = 'lista.php?grado=6-1';"```

Comment: (https://pruebasdm.000webhostapp.com) Intente entrar desde celular
Desde computador todo funciona normalmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es causado por un mal diseño responsivo. No solo sucede en celulares, para que suceda solo ocupas hacer la pagina mas pequeña, aquí en la imagen estoy usando la herramienta "Modo Diseño Responsivo" y el error aparece.

[image: img-div toma mas espacio]

Lo que pasa es que el `div` de la imagen responsiva (`<div class="col-md-6"><img src="img/galan.png" class="img-responsive"></div>`) toma parte del espacio de los botones, y cuando le das clic a un botón, realmente le estas dando clic al `div`.

El problema desaparece si eliminas la clase `col-md-6` del `div` de la imagen. En esta segunda imagen se muestra como, una vez eliminada la clase, el botón ya se obscurece, ya que ya estoy sobre el botón y no un `div`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]